# No Audio/Vibrate Notifications for Texts when Phone Locked

Tags: windows-10-mobile, sms, notifications, sound, vibration

A few days ago my Lumia 950 (AT&T) acted up, and now for some reason I get absolutely zero sound on texts **when the phone is locked**. Let be more clear: if I am using any app (or home screen, start screen, etc) and I get a text, the phone vibrates and dings just fine. When I set the phone down and it gets locked (either timeout or manual lock) I get **no sound or vibrate on text notifications**. I still get sound/vibrate on certain other notifications.

The notification **shows up** on the glance screen, and in my action menu, but it **makes no sound/vibration when the phone is locked.** This is a seriously large issue that's really irritating me. Yes, the "Ringer + Notifications" volume is all the way up. I've tried dropping the volume down to "Vibrate" and then back up to "10", but it still has the same issue. It *seems* to only be text messages that do it, but I don't get notifications for many other things (except email which I have sound turned off for).

I have done several soft-resets (both by pulling battery and using the power button) and nothing has worked.

**Phone**: Microsoft Lumia 950
**OS Build**: 10.0.14393.67
**Firmware Revision Number**: 01078.00038.16025.39033

The device did an update this morning, problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these two methods:

### Method 1

**Turn on Notifications on Lockscreen**

1. Go to *Settings->System->Notifications & Actions*.
2. Click on *Messaging*.
3. Turn the following options on.

   - Notification
   - Show notifications in Action center.

---

### Method 2

**Turn on Background usage**

1. Go to *Settings->System->Battery->Battery usage by App*.
2. Find Messaging.
3. Turn the Setting to *Always allowed in background*.
4. Go to *Settings->Privacy->Background apps*.
5. Turn on the option for Microsoft Messaging.

Comment: I toggled those settings (and a few others in those screens) on and off (they were all already on) and it cleared it up. Thanks! :)

Comment: @EBrown You are welcome. I'm glad you found my answer helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same symptoms and found that this setting was preventing the SMS notification sounds (and whatsapp etc):

Settings > System > Notification & Actions > **Show notifications on the lock screen and play notification sounds**.

This was turned off in my case.  the wording of this option was slightly confusing to me, because when the screen is off i wouldn't have called it the "lock screen".  however it does indeed block notification sounds when the screen is off.